# LIBGDX Collision detection in for each arrays

Tags: arrays, foreach, libgdx

I've a 2d game in libgdx, my game idea is like as defense game, heroes will appear of left of game screen and enemies will appear in right.

problem:
all enemies in enemies array doesn't take care about heroes except last hero in heroes array and run trough all heroes till to last hero then they take care to last hero! , for heroes is same scenario and they doesn't take care about all enemies except last enemy.
what is wrong?

```
private Array<Hero> heroes = new Array<>();
private Array<Enemy> enemies = new Array<>();

.....

public void overlapsDetector() {
    for (Hero hero : getHeroes()) {
        for (Enemy enemy : getEnemies()) {
            if (Intersector.overlaps(hero.getBounds(), enemy.getBounds())) {
                enemy.setEntityMode(EntityMode.SLASH);
                hero.setEntityMode(EntityMode.SLASH);
                enemy.setHealth(enemy.getHealth() - 1f);
                hero.setHealth(hero.getHealth() - 1f);
            } else {
                hero.setEntityMode(EntityMode.WALK);
                enemy.setEntityMode(EntityMode.WALK);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting your hero and enemy to SLASH or WALK state for every inner loop iteration. For example, if you set your hero to SLASH against the first enemy, but then detect it is out of bounds with respect to your last enemy, you set your hero back to WALK when you shouldn't.

Try something like this.

```
private Array<Hero> heroes = new Array<>();
private Array<Enemy> enemies = new Array<>();

.....

public void overlapsDetector() {

    for (Enemy enemy : getEnemies()) {
        enemy.setEntityMode(EntityMode.WALK); //initialise all enemies to walk
    }

    for (Hero hero : getHeroes()) {

        hero.setEntityMode(EntityMode.WALK); //initialise all heros to walk

        for (Enemy enemy : getEnemies()) {
            if (Intersector.overlaps(hero.getBounds(), enemy.getBounds())) {
                enemy.setEntityMode(EntityMode.SLASH);
                hero.setEntityMode(EntityMode.SLASH);
                enemy.setHealth(enemy.getHealth() - 1f);
                hero.setHealth(hero.getHealth() - 1f);
            } 
            //no else
        }
    }
}
```